# Regex include search terms in results

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to create a Regex expression in vb.net that includes the search term in the result (or have some way of finding which term was found).

For example, with these 2 sentences:

> hello Sailor my name is Bill
>
> hello Soldier my name is Bill

I can use this expression to look for either 'Sailor' or 'Soldier':

```
(?<=Sailor |Soldier ).+?(?= Bill)
```

... and this gives me:

> my name is

Which is the result I want, but I also need to know whether it matched on 'Sailor' **or** 'Soldier'. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found it when I did some tinkering. I just need this expression:

```
(?=Sailor |Soldier ).+?(?= Bill)
```

i.e. drop the < symbol from the start term.

Comment: If you also want to match Sailor or Soldier, you don't need the lookahead, you can just match them. `(?:Sailor |Soldier ).+?(?= Bill)`

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to first assert `Sailor`  and `Soldier`  using a lookahead and then matching them.

You can match them immediately, and perhaps add some word boundaries to prevent partial word matches:

```
\b(?:Sailor|Soldier) .+?(?= Bill)\b
```